# Failed to send attachment as mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send some generated report through email and I'm getting the following exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1764)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1523)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:453)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
        at centina.sa.server.system.SystemManager$6$1.call(SystemManager.java:1872)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
        at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:84)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1742)
```

code:

```
MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();
FileDataSource fileData = new FileDataSource( attachment ){
    public String getContentType(){
        return "application/octet-stream";
    }
};
att.setDataHandler(  new DataHandler( fileData ));
```

and I'm getting the error at line att.setDataHandler which is line number 1872 of system manager. Can someone explain why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Looks like you can't connect to the SMTP Server. Double check your settings.

Comment: Can you send mail without attachment?

Comment: Which mail server you are using now ?

Comment: I am able to send all the attachments except the attachments with large size(like 6,00,00)

Answer (score 0):

If, I try to send one attachment, then it is working fine, with this code. Try to match it, with what you have. Seems like there is some, flaw in settings. Though I am using `gmail`'s server, to send the mail, using this program.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;

public class SendMailExample {

    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String subject;
    private String messageBody;
    private String fileName;
    private String host;

    private Properties properties;

    private MimeMessage message;
    private BodyPart messageBodyPart;
    private Multipart multipart;

    private Authenticator authenticator;

    public SendMailExample () {
        from = "sender@gmail.com";
        to = "recipient@gmail.com";
        subject = "Subject Testing";
        messageBody = "<html><body><h1>HAVE FAITH, AND STAY" +
                    " CALM :-) I AM WITH YOU, OKAY :-)</h1></body></html>";
        fileName = "Test.txt";
        host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        authenticator = new SMTPAuthenticator ();
        properties = System.getProperties ();
        properties.put ( "mail.smtp.host", host );
        properties.put ( "mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true" );
        properties.put ( "mail.smtp.port", "587" );
        properties.put ( "mail.smtp.auth", "true" );
    }

    private void sendMail ( String from, String to,
                    String subject, String messageBody, String fileName ) {
        try {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance ( properties, authenticator );
            message = new MimeMessage ( session );
            message.setFrom ( new InternetAddress ( from ) );
            message.addRecipient ( Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                new InternetAddress ( to ) );
            message.setSubject ( subject );

            multipart = new MimeMultipart ();
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart ();
            messageBodyPart.setContent ( messageBody, "text/html" );
            multipart.addBodyPart ( messageBodyPart );

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart ();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource ( fileName );
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler ( new DataHandler ( source ) );
            messageBodyPart.setFileName ( fileName );
            multipart.addBodyPart ( messageBodyPart );

            message.setContent ( multipart );

            Transport.send ( message );
            System.out.println ( "Message send successfully...." );
        } catch ( Exception me ) {
            me.printStackTrace ();
        }
    } 

    private void performTask () {
        sendMail ( from, to, subject, messageBody, fileName );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        new SendMailExample ().performTask ();
    }
}

/**
  * SimpleAuthenticator is used to do simple authentication
  * when the SMTP server requires it.
  */

class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "myemail@gmail.com";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PASSWORD = "password";

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication () {
        String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER;
        String password = SMTP_AUTH_PASSWORD;

        return new PasswordAuthentication( username,  password );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with this [JavaMail FAQ entry for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Most likely you have a firewall or anti-virus program preventing you from connecting.

Comment: He has connected. The error comes in reading a response. Maybe the attachment was too big?

Comment: Ok, looking at the stack trace more carefully, it seems to be failing when connecting to the SMTP server and reading the response from the server.  I'd still like to see the debug output.  Possibly it's failing because a non-SSL connection is being made to an SSL port.

Comment: i am getting this error only if the attachment consists of large data like 6,00,000 lines. if the attachment has less data till 1,00,000 lines the mail was successfully sent

Comment: There's no way the server knows how many lines are in your attachment at the time you're connecting to the server.  Are you sure the stack trace above is from such a failure?  Can you post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug)?

Answer (score 0):

If you send letters with small attachment, problem not in your code.

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

This error mean server drops connection, not client. I suppose it happens when you send too big attachment. Unfortunately, this is server side problem and you cannot solve it on client side. Try somehow decrease attachment size (zip it or use different report format). Maybe would be better send direct download link, not full report.